# How to replace a analytics "push"?

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I have a page that requires tracking in Google Analytics. The page has multiple questions on it and has a button that you can click to go the next page. Each question is multiple choice and I am trying to track drop-off points. So essentially, I track a "code" per session, on every click.

So if the user answers question 1, I track:

```
Page1-Question1
```

If they answer question 2, I track:

```
Page2-Question2
```

If they answer question 3, I track:

```
Page2-Question3
```

And so on. The problem is, I need to track "drop off" points. In other words, if the user answers question 2, I need to "forget" that they pressed question 1, so there is only ONE entry stored for question 2 for that user.

Alternatively, I need a view in analytics that allows me to see only the LATEST tracked click of the user.

Unfortunately, my Google Analytics skills are limited and I can't seem to find a way to do either of these. I managed to do part that fires the tracking per question and essentially I track it as follows:

```
gaTrack('/quiz-1','quiz1--' + 'page:' + pg_num + '-question:'+question);
```

The problem is that this could be called:

```
gaTrack('/quiz-1','quiz1--' + 'page:' + 1 + '-question:'+1);
```

Then

```
gaTrack('/quiz-1','quiz1--' + 'page:' + 1 + '-question:'+2);
```

Then

```
gaTrack('/quiz-1','quiz1--' + 'page:' + 1 + '-question:'+3);
```

And then I just have the list of questions the user clicked on, rather than the LAST list the user clicked on.

Any ideas?

Comment: you should look at event tracking.  not sure what that gatrack is https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

Comment: Are these questions actually new pages, where the user navigates to, and that are pushed into GA as pageviews anyway? Or these questions are displayed on the same page, one by one, e.g. by a Javascript code?

Answer (score 0):

Just track the pages as they are. Use the correct tracking method in JavaScript.

You probably mean this function:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', [page], [fieldsObject]);
```

See: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages

Now as the pages are tracked use the metric: exits. (ga:exits https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets)

Every exit is the last page a user visited in his session. There are your drop off points. No further implementation needed.